# No se me centra el menu en css y html

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

yo quiero que cuando este en tamaño para celulares en la pagina el menu este centrado y abajo del logo y e titulo  , el problema es que no se me centra

```css
* {
  max-width: 2000PX;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

body{
  background: #786767;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height:90px;
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}

.container-header{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex; 
}

.container-logo-title{
  display: flex;
}

.container-logo-title img{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top:5px 
}



.container-logo-title h1{
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 23px;
  margin-left: 10PX;
  font-size: 25px; 
}

.container-menu{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.menu ul{
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px; 
}

.menu ul li{
  list-style: none;
  float:right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#check{
  display: none;
}

.icon-menu{ 
  display: none;  
}

.menu li  a {
  padding: 15px;
  position: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
}

/*efecto de ponerse en color rojo cuando pase el mouse */
.menu li  a:hover {
  background: #9D0B1D;
  border-radius: 20px;
}



@media screen and (max-width:880px){
  .menu li  a {
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 19px;
  }

  .container-menu{
    position:absolute;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .menu {
    background: white;
    margin-top :88px;
    margin-right:0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 888;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 90000;
  }

  .container-logo-title img{
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:900px){
  .container-logo-title h1{ 
    margin-top: 29px;
    font-size: 14;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <DIV CLASS="container-header"> 
    <DIV CLASS= "container-logo-title">
<img src="imagenes/logo.jpg" class="img-logo">
    <H1>MELAMOBLAMIENTOS</H1></DIV>

     <input type="checkbox" id="check"  >
<label for="check" class="icon-menu"></label>

 
        
        <div class="container-menu">
<nav class= "menu">
    
<ul>
<li><a href="#Inicio">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="#Servicios">Servicios</a></li>
<li><a href="#Trabajos">Trabajos</a></li>
<li><a href="#Contacto">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
            </div>
        </DIV>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entendí, puedes usar flex box.

```
.menu{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Comment: gracias por ayudarme ,perdon por las molestias es que soy nueva

Answer (score 1):

Es un poco confuso tu código, tanto el HTML como CSS, hice algunas modificaciones al CSS para poder centrar correctamente el menú con flexbox, utilizando el media query ya existente:

```
.menu ul {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
* {
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

body{
  background: #786767;
}

header {
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.container-header{
  max-width: 2000px;
}

.container-logo-title {
  display: flex;
}

.container-logo-title img{
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top:5px 
}


.container-logo-title h1{
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 23px;
  margin-left: 10PX;
  font-size: 25px; 
}

.menu ul{
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px; 
}

.menu ul li{
  list-style: none;
  float:right;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#check{
  display: none;
}

.icon-menu{ 
  display: none;  
}

.menu li  a {
  padding: 15px;
  position: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
}

/*efecto de ponerse en color rojo cuando pase el mouse */
.menu li  a:hover {
  background: #9D0B1D;
  border-radius: 20px;
}



@media screen and (max-width:880px){
  .menu li  a {
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 19px;
  }

  .menu {
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 888;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 90000;
  }

  .menu ul {
    justify-content: center;
  }

.menu ul li {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

  .container-logo-title img{
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:900px){
  .container-logo-title h1{ 
    margin-top: 29px;
    font-size: 14;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container-header"> 
    <div class= "container-logo-title">
      <img src="imagenes/logo.jpg" class="img-logo">
      <h1>MELAMOBLAMIENTOS</h1>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="check"  >
    <label for="check" class="icon-menu"></label>

    <div class="container-menu">
      <nav class= "menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#Inicio">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Servicios">Servicios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Trabajos">Trabajos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Contacto">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```